# HTTP.Body parameters error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have this code, I need to pass parameters by BODY, but I get a "rare" error. Can anybody help me? THX!!

**This is the error**

> > Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda33f4cd80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:.../users.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http:.../users.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response})

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

//
// The problem is the following 4 lines, if I tell, there is no error, but of course, I can not register a user
//

do {

    request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(bodyParams, options: [])

} catch {

    IsRegistered(isRegistered: false, messageString: "Error al parsear los datos.")

}


        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

            if (error != nil) {

               // ERROR HERE
               // ERROR HERE
               // ERROR HERE
               print(error)

            } else {

               ...

            }
}
```

**bodyParams is a Dictionary**

I see that "everyone" uses this method to pass parameters by body, but I do not work for me :(

**EDIT**

```
var bodyParams: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary()
bodyParams["firstName"] = currentUser.getFirstName()
bodyParams["lastName"] = currentUser.getLastName()
bodyParams["gender"] = currentUser.getGender()
bodyParams["birthday"] = currentUser.getBirthday()
```

Comment: whats your **bodyParams** contains

Comment: hi! @Anbu.Karthik go to EDIT!

Comment: How do you want your JSON to look like?